# Refactoring existing Design to get partial object data

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, optimization, refactoring

I have a hierarchical data  structure (using Entity beans)like say a Book Class which has a Book ID and references  to a bunch of Chapter classes.And each chapter class has a Chapter number and references to a number of Page classes. In my Display class, I would like to display the book id of a Book object.

But when I call getBook() , the existing code loads up the chapters and pages too, even though I just want to get only the Book ID from the Book object.This is resulting in heavy database querying.

I am looking for a design pattern to solve this problem.Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) design pattern.

Here is a good example.
    http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/EJB.htm#EJB133